# Image tag from google chart not displayed

Tags: html

I have the following image tag, which isn't being displayed:

```
<img src="https://www.google.com/chart?cht=tx&amp;chf=bg,s,FFFFFF00&amp;chco=000000&amp;chl=test3">
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/evs7gsk3/8/

There is an associated console error: `GET https://www.google.com/chart?cht=tx&chf=bg,s,FFFFFF00&chco=000000&chl=test3 400 (OK)`

The image can be viewed by pasting the url into the browser and replacing all occurences of `&amp;` by `&`. Beware though, when you do so, you'll have the image in your cache and will not be able to reproduce the error unless you clear/deactivate your cache.

Question: Why does this happen and what can I do to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be some sort of cross origin issue. Change the image url to http and load the page with https:

`Jsfiddle:`https://jsfiddle.net/p9q7v2tm/

Comment: Thanks a lot, this saved my life :)